# Why ls and du show different size?

Tags: linux, ls

I am downloading a file with rtorrent,

When I check the folder that the file is located on, the filesize with **`ls`** command is **4.4GB** but when I check the disk with **`du`** command it shows me **219MB**, also the same problem with `df` command that seems just calculate the 219MB one.

---

Here is the my console result

```
root@SERVER:/home/.root/TMP/tnt/d1/xxx# dir -alh

total 219M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K 2010-01-10 15:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4.0K 2010-01-10 15:30 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4.4G 2010-01-11 10:55 yyy.mkv

root@SERVER:/home/.root/TMP/tnt/d1/xxx# du -h

219M    .

root@SERVER:/home/.root/TMP/tnt/d1/xxx#
```

Comment: I ran across this same problem today after growing a disk image using `qemu-img resize`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). `ls` is reporting the allocated size; `du` is reporting the amount of space actually used.

As your torrent client downloads more it will fill in the gaps and the `du`-reported size will grow to match what `ls` reports.

To force `du` and `df` to include sparces, from the `man du` the second option listed is `--apparent-size`:

```
du -s -B1 --apparent-size
```