# Why is there a huge discrepancy between file sizes reported by du versus ls?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-management, tar

On a server, I have a directory `/opt/kafka/data/topics`.

```
$ du -hs /opt/kafka/data/topics
52M     /opt/kafka/data/topics
```

When I tar this directory like

```
$ tar czfv /tmp/topics.tar.gz /opt/kafka/data/topics
```

I get a file size that makes sense

```
$ ls -alh /tmp/topics.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  11M Jan 12 15:15 kafka
```

However, when I download `topics.tar.gz` to my local OS X computer and extract it, **it occupies 10GB!**

---

Upon examining the contents of `/opt/kafka/data/topics` on the server more closely, I noticed that according to `ls` it contains many 10MB files:

```
$ find /opt/kafka/data -type f -exec ls -alh {} \;
... [output]
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 10M Jan 12 02:45 /opt/kafka/data/topics/user-entities-KTABLE-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000178-changelog-1/00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 10M Jan 12 02:45 /opt/kafka/data/topics/user-entities-KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000123-repartition-2/00000000000000000012.index
... [and many more]
```

`du` reports that each of these 10MB files are 0 bytes:

```
$ du -h /opt/kafka/data/topics/user-entities-KTABLE-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000178-changelog-1/00000000000000000000.index
0       /opt/kafka/data/topics/user-entities-KTABLE-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000178-changelog-1/00000000000000000000.index
```

So, what is going on? Obviously I am missing something here:

- `du` reports 52M total. This makes sense because the device that `/opt/kafka/data` is mounted on is only 5GBs, `df` reports that it's only 2% full and everything is still working.
- `tar` gzips the contents to 10M. This makes sense too.
- `ls` reports that many of the files are 10M on disk and when I extract the archive I get 10GBs.
- `du` reports that each of these same files are 0 bytes.
- `mount` reports that `/dev/sdc on /opt/kafka/data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

Nothing adds up. Is there some kind of transparent on-disk compression I am not aware of?

Comment: Multiple hardlinks to the same file inside the source directory? Sparse files?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no hardlinks; yes, the 10MB files (as reported by `ls`) are sparse. They are reported as 0 bytes by `du` and are indeed empty

Comment: How about `tar --sparse` option while creating the archive? Does it help? [Link](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/sparse.html).

Comment: Help with what? The problem isn't that the tar is large when I create it. The tar is quite small. The problem is that on-disk, these 10MB sparse files seem to occupy 0 bytes. How can that be? Is there some sort of compression at the filesystem level? Why does `ls` report 10MB but `du` reports 0 bytes?

Comment: Although... my `man tar` on OS X does include an option `-S` for extracting: `(x mode only) Extract files as sparse files.  For every block on disk, check first if it contains only NULL bytes and seek over it otherwise.  This works similiar to the conv=sparse option of dd.` This may be helpful.

Comment: I think you may be on the right track. Write your own answer if you resolve the problem. Leave me a comment and I will upvote the answer.

Comment: Note from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file): "Apple's HFS+ does not provide for sparse files, but in OS X, the virtual file system layer supports storing them in any supported file system, including HFS+". Check if your target filesystem supports sparse files in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I saw that note too, and I am indeed on HFS+. But what I wonder now is why the `-S` option did not work (I tried extracting again with -S and got 10GB from the 10MB tar). Maybe I need to compress with `--sparse` too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why ls and du show different size?](https://superuser.com/questions/94217/why-ls-and-du-show-different-size)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, all the files are sparse.  This type of thing actually confuses a lot of people the first time they deal with it, so don't feel bad.

### What's actually going on here with the values reported by `ls` and `du`?

This is most easily explained with an example.

Say you create an empty file, and then write 1MB of data to it starting right at the beginning.  The resultant file will be 1MB in size, and take up 1MB on disk.  Both `ls` and `du` will report the same 1MB size for the file.

Now say instead you create an empty file, and then call `seek()` to move 1MB into the file, and then write one byte.  The resultant file will appear to be 1MB + 1 byte long, but there's only actually 1 byte of data in it.

On older filesystems, the second file would have taken a very long time to write that  1 byte of data, because the OS would be busy writing out 1MB of null bytes before it wrote out that final 1 byte of actual data.

This inefficiency (both in terms of time to create the file, and space used on disk) is where sparse files come in.  Instead of writing out that 1MB of null bytes, an OS that supports sparse files (like all modern UNIX systems) will annotate in that filesystem's metadata that the region form 0-1MB is empty, and then only store that single byte you wrote.  As a result, the file will appear to be 1MB + 1 byte long, but on disk it will only take up 1 byte.  Additionally, when something goes to read that file, any regions the OS has annotated as empty will just read back as null bytes (so it looks no different to user programs from the first file).

This is where the discrepancy between the values reported by `ls` and `du` comes from.  By default, `ls` reports the apparent size of files (that is, how much data would you read if you started reading the file at the first byte and read all the way to the end), while `du` reports the actual space used on disk by the file (usually not including other space saving tricks done by the OS like transparent compression).  `du` agrees with `df` in this case because `df` only reports the amount of space that is actually physically being used on disk.

By changing that `ls -l` command to `ls -ls`, you will get an extra column showing the actual on-disk size for files, which should agree with `du`.

Comment: I don’t feel bad, don’t worry ;) Thanks for pointing out the -s switch. I’ll look into that.