Why is there a discrepancy between du and ls (on Linux)?
Please see the following image:
enter image description here
You can see that the lichess_db file is listed as 209G in ls, but du -hd1 indicates a folder size of only 196G. Why does that happen? Which is correct?
Edit: I'm not sure whether the thread referenced in the comments answers my question or not. If it does, I don't understand why this would be a sparse file, as it is fully downloaded and a PGN file is just a large text file as far as I'm aware.

Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/q/94217/673426

What’s your filesystem? Does it perhaps use compression? Is the file sparse? There could be any number of reasons.

I am going to hazard a guess here due to non-default ls output & say that ls is giving you an answer based on "1k = 1000", where as du is based on "1k = 1024".
